# Need my XSLT to only output from the XML a specific author if available

Tags: xml, xslt

I am attempting to only output from my XML Author attribute that is equal to **McGraw-Hill**, I am quite new to XSLT I would like some idea of what I need to change to make it work as intended.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Book's list</title>
                    <link   type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="bookstore/book">
                <xsl:sort select="year" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="bookstore/book/authors">
                    <xsl:if test="author = 'McGraw-Hill'">
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:apply-templates>      
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="bookstore">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="book">

        <div class="book">
            <br/>
            <strong> <xsl:value-of select="title" /> </strong>
            <span> Price: $ <xsl:value-of select="price" /> </span>
        </div>

        <div class="author">
            Author(s):
            <br/>
            <xsl:for-each select="authors/author" >
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <br/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML itself does not contain the author and I want it to not output anything but it lists off all the books in descending publishing date which is intended just not wanting the books to be included if it does not contain the author.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Portfolio4.xsl"?>
<bookstore>

  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <authors>   
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    </authors>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>

  <book category="children">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <authors>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    </authors>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>

  <book category="web">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <authors>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    </authors>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
  </book>

  <book category="web" cover="paperback">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <authors>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    </authors>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>

  <book category= "engineering" cover="hardcover">
    <title lang="en">Network Fundamentals, CCNA Exploration Companion Guide</title>
    <authors>   
        <author>Mark Dye</author>
        <author>Rick McDonald</author>
        <author>Antoon Rufi</author>
    </authors>
    <year>2007</year>
    <price>7.25</price>
  </book>

  <book category= "engineering" cover="hardcover">
    <title lang="en">Modern Operating Systems</title>
    <authors>
        <author>Andrew S. Tanenbaum</author>
        <author>Herbert Bos</author>
    </authors>
    <year>2001</year>
    <price>14.94</price>
  </book>

 <book category= "engineering" cover="hardcover">
    <title lang="en">The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 1: Fundamental Algorithms</title>
    <authors>   
        <author>Donald Ervin Knuth</author>
    </authors>
    <year>1997</year>
    <price>75.32</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

> Edit: added the XML, and the required output would be any books that contain the stated author in my question would show in the output.

Comment: Can you share the input XML and the desired output? BTW `author == McGraw Hill` is incorrect. You need to modify `author = 'McGraw Hill'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this block of code

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="bookstore/book">
<xsl:sort select="year" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
<xsl:for-each select="bookstore/book/authors">
    <xsl:if test="author = 'McGraw-Hill'">
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

The main problem being you can't nest `xsl:for-each` in `xsl:apply-templates`.

You should simplify it to this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="bookstore/book[authors/author='McGraw-Hill']">
    <xsl:sort select="year" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

(Of course, this won't return any results in your sample XML as it doesn't have any books authored by them).

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Book's list</title>
                    <link   type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="bookstore/book[authors/author='McGraw-Hill']">
                    <xsl:sort select="year" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>      
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book">
        <div class="book">
            <br/>
            <strong> <xsl:value-of select="title" /> </strong>
            <span> Price: $ <xsl:value-of select="price" /> </span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
            Author(s):
            <br/>
            <xsl:for-each select="authors/author" >
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <br/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```